# Container stop's sending logs to AWS CW

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

yes so I've been following these docs from docker logging driver https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/

when I'm using my custom image my container is not sending logs to CW but when I used an image from docker hub ex. nginx, lamp stack it is successfully sending logs (tested using docker-compose).

Also when using docker run it is successfully sending logs but when restarting the container it stops sending logs again. is there some kind of command needed to add in my compose file or when using docker run??

Comment: Here's my " docker run -it -p 91:80 -p 3306:3306 --log-driver="awslogs" --log-opt awslogs-region="ap-southeast-1" --log-opt awslogs-group="sample-log-group" --log-opt awslogs-stream="sample-stream-log" lamp:latest bash "

Comment: docker-compose file. don't mind the naming from log group and logs stream.

https://imgur.com/V9rvH3L

Comment: Dockerfile.

https://imgur.com/0okE5ch

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see docker logs install portainer using docker , only two command you need to run . portainer will help you to manage docker logs